# Apply succinct function over subsets of columns of data frames in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration, mean, tidyverse

I have a list (28 items) of dataframes (12 columns, 8 rows) named "n.l.df".
Statistics need to be applied row-wise on columns 1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:12, separately, within each dataframe. I am iterating through the list, calculating stats by doing the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
avgs <- n.l.df
avgs <- lapply(avgs, function(x) {
x[1,1] <-mean(as.numeric(x[1,1:3]))
x[2,1] <-mean(as.numeric(x[2,1:3]))
x[3,1] <-mean(as.numeric(x[3,1:3]))
x[4,1] <-mean(as.numeric(x[4,1:3]))
x[5,1] <-mean(as.numeric(x[5,1:3]))
x[6,1] <-mean(as.numeric(x[6,1:3]))
x[7,1] <-mean(as.numeric(x[7,1:3]))
x[8,1] <-mean(as.numeric(x[8,1:3]))
x[1,4] <-mean(as.numeric(x[1,4:6]))
x[2,4] <-mean(as.numeric(x[2,4:6]))
x[3,4] <-mean(as.numeric(x[3,4:6]))
x[4,4] <-mean(as.numeric(x[4,4:6]))
x[5,4] <-mean(as.numeric(x[5,4:6]))
x[6,4] <-mean(as.numeric(x[6,4:6]))
x[7,4] <-mean(as.numeric(x[7,4:6]))
x[8,4] <-mean(as.numeric(x[8,4:6]))
x[1,7] <-mean(as.numeric(x[1,7:9]))
x[2,7] <-mean(as.numeric(x[2,7:9]))
x[3,7] <-mean(as.numeric(x[3,7:9]))
x[4,7] <-mean(as.numeric(x[4,7:9]))
x[5,7] <-mean(as.numeric(x[5,7:9]))
x[6,7] <-mean(as.numeric(x[6,7:9]))
x[7,7] <-mean(as.numeric(x[7,7:9]))
x[8,7] <-mean(as.numeric(x[8,7:9]))
x[1,10] <-mean(as.numeric(x[1,10:12]))
x[2,10] <-mean(as.numeric(x[2,10:12]))
x[3,10] <-mean(as.numeric(x[3,10:12]))
x[4,10] <-mean(as.numeric(x[4,10:12]))
x[5,10] <-mean(as.numeric(x[5,10:12]))
x[6,10] <-mean(as.numeric(x[6,10:12]))
x[7,10] <-mean(as.numeric(x[7,10:12]))
x[8,10] <-mean(as.numeric(x[8,10:12]))
return(x)
})
```

This works nicely and I can strip out the unnecessary values in columns 2,3,5,6,8,9,11, and 12 when needed. I like that I do not have to gather the dataframes into long form and keeping it as a list of dataframes is preferable.

Clearly, this way is too repetitive and I think there must be a way to do a nested lapply/apply, but it is beyond my level. How can I simplify and shorten this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse)

# For reproducibility
set.seed(100)

# list of 28 random data frames
df_list <- rerun(28, data.frame(replicate(12,sample(1:100,8))))

# Use map to iterate over the list, using rowMeans and select to get means of select columns.
map(df_list, ~mutate(., rm_1_3 = rowMeans(select(., 1:3)),
                           rm_4_6 = rowMeans(select(., 4:6)),
                           rm_7_9 = rowMeans(select(., 7:9)),
                           rm_10_12 = rowMeans(select(., 10:12))))


[[1]]
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8  X9 X10 X11 X12   rm_1_3   rm_4_6   rm_7_9 rm_10_12
1 31 55 21 43 35 34 21 13  45  58  46  31 35.66667 37.33333 26.33333 45.00000
2 26 17 36 17 95 86 31 23  36  96  60  73 26.33333 66.00000 30.00000 76.33333
3 55 62 99 76 69 77 33 59 100  65  91  89 72.00000 74.00000 64.00000 81.66667
4  6 86 67 86 87 81 20 21  44  61  96  21 53.00000 84.66667 28.33333 59.33333
5 45 27 52 53 18 58 23 45  24  83   4  35 41.33333 43.00000 30.66667 40.66667
6 46 38 68 27 60 47 27 62  66  74  55  43 50.66667 44.66667 51.66667 57.33333
7 77 72 51 46 94 74 56 91  39  79  69  86 66.66667 71.33333 62.00000 78.00000
8 35 63 70 87 13 83 24 63  31   9  24  37 56.00000 61.00000 39.33333 23.33333
```

This will give you a list of 28 data frames, with 4 columns of statistics added to each.  If you just want the means, then substitute `transmute` for `mutate`

Comment: Thanks, Jake! I did not know about the map function. It works beautifully once I forced my objects into numeric dataframe.

Comment: It's specifically from 'purrr`, which is the tidyverse set of functional programming tools.  I'd recommend reading up on it.